# jquery closest() selecting

Tags: jquery, xhtml, closest

I am having issues getting my remove element function working.

I have this function:

```
//Remove an Item From Any Group
function deleteItem (selector) {
  $(selector).closest("li").fadeOut(500, function() { 
    $(selector).closest("li").remove();
  });
}
```

Then this to call it,

```
$("a.delete").live('click', function() {
  deleteItem("li span.delete a.delete");
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="" width="40" height="40" class="image"/><span><a href="#">Drinkers Pub</a></span><span class="delete"><a href="javascript:;" class="delete">delete</a></span></li>
  <li><img src="" width="40" height="40" class="image"/><span><a href="#">Drinkers Pub</a></span><span class="delete"><a href="javascript:;" class="delete">delete</a></span></li>
  <li><img src="" width="40" height="40" class="image"/><span><a href="#">Drinkers Pub</a></span><span class="delete"><a href="javascript:;" class="delete">delete</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is it is only removing the first LI in the list no matter which link. 
I thought closest picks the closest element from the event. IN this case the click of the delete button.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the deleteItem function a selector that gets you all of the delete links.
You'll want something more like this.

```
function deleteItem (link) {
  link.closest("li").fadeOut(500, function() { 
    link.closest("li").remove();
  });
}

$("a.delete").live('click', function() {
  deleteItem($(this));
});
```